# Is it possible to enable SSL with out a domain name or ip?

Tags: ssl, nginx, openssl, ssl-certificate, openresty

I am trying to add security to my nginx server application. This server wouldn't be hosted on any specific domain neither will have a static ip.

Is SSL still an option for me to enable security to my server? If not what are my other options?

I am using openresty as base image for my nginx docker.

Comment: SSL is not an option from my understanding, caus you need domain or static ip to use it with "Common Name" certificate attribute. If you need to secure your server application only for personal use you can tunnel your connection through SSH for example or try something like VPN, but in both cases you must provide actual IP before connecting to the server. You could implement any custom complex security system with OpenResty but it wouldn't be supported by any browser out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally, the **subject** of a certificate for a website is a hostname. However, if you use the **Subject Alternative Name** (SAN) extension, you can specify a subject more flexibly. For example, you can use an email address. See *"3.2. Subject Alternative Name"* in *"[Illustrated X.509 Certificate](https://medium.com/@darutk/illustrated-x-509-certificate-84aece2c5c2e)"* for details.

[image: The definition of SubjectAltName]

The answer to the question *"Is it possible to enable SSL without a domain name or ip?"* is yes, and I think that TLS (SSL) is one of good options for your server's security.

Comment: Thanks alot @Takahiko Kawasaki for taking time looking into the case. For my service there would just be two clients always and hence my server wont he user facing . My approach here is using self signed certificate to establish a secure communication channel between my client and nginx server. So from what your saying i believe this is possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. In addition, I think you can keep using a hostname as a subject for your purpose if you don't want to bother. Instead of checking the value of the subject of the certificate, it is enough (and actually more than enough) for the client application to check whether the "thumbprint" of the entire certificate matches the expected one. FYI: [RFC 8705](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8705) Section 2.2 shows how to use a self-signed certificate for [OAuth 2.0 Client Authentication](https://medium.com/@darutk/oauth-2-0-client-authentication-4b5f929305d4).